# Detect objects loaded asynchronously in promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise

Well, it's hard to explain. I'll show an example so it will be easier to understand.
Lets asume I have `html` with 3 `divs`:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

and I want to load button to each of the `div` and make functions for loading them:

```
function LoadA() {
    $('#a').html('<button id="aB" > a Button </button>');
}
function LoadB() {
    $('#b').html('<button id="bB" > b Button </button>');
}
function LoadC() {
    $('#c').html('<button id="cB" > c Button </button>');
}
```

I have a function which put `console.log()` when button is clicked:

```
function DisplayLog() {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
}
```

Ok, so I can make it like this

```
function GeneralFunction() {
    LoadA(function () {
        LoadB(function () {
            LoadC(function () {
                DisplayLog();
            })
        })
    })
}
```

So when I click the funcion, `log` appears in the `console`. But in this case, function is loaded after function. I want to load it asynchronously, so I decided to make it in `Promise`:

```
function GeneralFunction() {
    Promise.all([LoadA(), LoadB(), LoadC()]).then(function () {
        DisplayLog();
    })
}
```

But this does not work. I think because of load this function on not changed `DOM`(?), but I'm no sure. Any tips to solve this?

Code above is only to help with description of the problem.

Comment: Did you change definition of methods LoadA, LoadB and LoadC to be promises? Promise.all accepts array of promisses.  If not, take a look at : https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Well I don't know if is your example is just a simple demonstration but I don't see any promise being returned on each of the load functions.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that promise is working, because I add `console.log` to each function, and in promise's `callback`, and the "promise's callback console.log" appears last. In my program it take longer time to load all divs, because it connects with controller and returns partial views, so I'm sure it's not because it was fast enought to get the console logs from functions first. It's another issue, probably that `DisplayLog()` is called not in changed `DOM`

Comment: If I make `LoadA(function(){ DisplayLog(); });` It's  working for this div. But when I make `LoadA().Promise().then(function(){ DisplayLog(); }` it is not working